# Replacing Matrix Values in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, replace

I have a matrix such as

```
M = [ 1 3 2 4;
      3 3 2 1;
      2 4 1 3]
```

which has a base `A = [ 1 2 3 4];`

I also have another base `B = [103 104 105 106];`

I need to replace the values of A with values of B inside M. So my new M should be:

```
M1 = [ 103  105 104 106;
       105  105 104 103;
       104  106 103 105];
```

The elements are random numbers so I need to use indice one to one connection between A nd B. 
Should I  mention it? of course NO FOR LOOPS :D
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for you:

```
sum(bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@eq, M, reshape(A,1,1,[])), reshape(B,1,1,[])), 3)
```

It's rather fast.

#### Benchmark

Here's the benchmarking code:

```
%// bsxfun party
tic
for k = 1:10000
    M1 = sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@eq,M,reshape(A,1,1,[])),reshape(B,1,1,[])),3);
end
toc

%// Using ismember
tic
for k = 1:10000
    [idx,b] = ismember(M,A);      
    M(idx) = B(b(idx));
end
toc

%// Using a simple loop
tic
for k = 1:10000
    M1 = M;
    for t = 1:length(A)
        M1(M == A(t)) = B(t);
    end
end
toc
```

The results are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.030135 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.094354 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.007410 seconds.
```

So this one-liner is faster than the elegant solution with `ismember`, but the simple (JIT-accelerated) loop beats both. Surprising, no? :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure the new `M` contains *only* elements from the new base (same for the old `M` and the old base), you can use the second output of `ismember`:

```
 >> [~,b] = ismember(M,A);      
 >> M = B(b)
 M =
    103   105   104   106
    105   105   104   103
    104   106   103   105
```

Comment: Elegant, but surprisingly slower than a loop :)

Comment: What I was hoping to come up with! Edited slightly so it will also work if not all elements of `M` occur in `A`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: omitting the `idx` is allowed when those  conditions I mentioned hold. I think for this case it's more elegant to omit them, so I'll rollback if you don't mind.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Ah, I think you edited an older version :)

Comment: @EitanT: surprising? hardly, if you look at `edit ismember` :)

Answer (score 2):

If your base is a simple function of your old base it can be trivial:

```
M1 = M + 102;
```

Otherwise this is a way:

```
M1 = M
for t = 1:length(A)
    M1(M==A(t)) = B(t)
end
```

Based on the answer of @Rody an other solution:

```
[idx,b] = ismember(M,A);      
M(idx) = B(b(idx))
```

The difference is that this will not break if `A` does not contain all elements of `M`. (Probably should not occur if it is a proper basis).

Comment: The last one is probably how I would prefer it myself.